# Invalid expression term 'long'

Tags: c#, chromium

I get an error "Invalid expression term 'long'" in the code below:

```
if (Int64.TryParse(Response.ToString(), out long time) == false)
{
    this.ResponseStatus = "Unexpected Server Response!";
    return false;
}
this.ResponseStatus = "License OK";
return true;
```

[image]

Comment: please provide the code of the whole method

Answer (score 0):

The `Int64.TryParse()` method takes arguments `string s` and `out long result`.
I can recreate the same error you are getting, but with `ref` instead of `out`. Here's an example:

```
private void Test(ref long result) 
{ 
    //some code in here
}
```

I try to call the method like this:

```
Test(ref long time);
```

And with this I get the same errors your are getting.

Now the question is, why you are getting the exact same error while using `out`.
If you don't need the variable `long time` afterwards, you could just call the `TryParse` method like this:

```
Int64.TryParse(Response.ToString(), out _);
```

The underscore `_` just discards the value that would be outputted.

But I think you just didn't provide the correct code corresponding the error. You should provide us with the whole and correct code, so we can help.

Answer (score -1):

The code you show is not the code that causes those compiler errors. You must have something that looks like this:

```
if (Int64.TryParse(long time) == false)
```

This yields exactly those three errors:

```
Error   CS1525  Invalid expression term 'long'
Error   CS1003  Syntax error, ',' expected
Error   CS0103  The name 'time' does not exist in the current context
```

The format you need is exactly as you've posted it, so fix your code so it looks like the code in your question.

Comment: if (Response.ToString() == "69")
                    {
                        this.ResponseStatus = "";
                        Dead.GoKill();
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (Int64.TryParse(Response.ToString(), out long time) == false)
                    {
                        this.ResponseStatus = "Unexpected Server Response!";
                        return false;
                    }
                    this.ResponseStatus = "License OK";
                    return true;
                }

Comment: Wait, do you have like Visual Studio 2012? You need at least C# 7 (VS 2017) for inline out variable declarations. If you have a very old Visual Studio version, you need to declare  `long time` before the call to `TryParse()`, but you'd better update your Visual Studio.

Comment: visual studio problem ?